# C# Meta-information for object serialisation

Tags: c#, serialization, encryption, compression, deserialization

Say I have an object called `data` which contains a variety of information. Let's say for argument that there is actually quite a lot of stuff within the `data` graph.

If I serialise it using `BinaryFormatter` then I get a file which is, say, 5Mb.
If I encapsulate the serialisation stream in a `GZipStream` then I get a much smaller file, say, 1Mb.

I can, if I want, encrypt the stream while compressing it, or encrypt the stream without compressing it.

The issue is: I need to know what was done during serialisation so that I know what to do when I deserialise it.

One technique would be to use a different file extension. For example, an uncompressed, unencrypted file might have a .dat extension, .zdat for compressed, .cdat for encrypted, and .czdat for compressed and encrypted.

This would work, but it introduces a potential problem: What if the user changes the extension, etc. It also means that if I want to associate the files in Windows, there are 4 extensions instead of 1 which need to be associated - quadrupling the risk of collisions with existing the associations.

If I wrap my data object in a simple class:

```
[Serializable]
public class SerialisationContainer
{
   public string SerialisedData { get; private set; }

   public bool Compressed { get; private set; }
   public bool Encrypted { get; private set; }

   public SerialisationContainer()
   {
     // etc...
   }

   public object GetObject()
   {
     // etc...
   }
}
```

then I'm basically serialising an object which has a serialised stream in it which may be compressed and/or encrypted, but we don't know or care at this point because the meta-information is stored in the `SerialisationContainer`.

What do you think? I'm basically just curious what you think of this method, and what you do in similar situations. I think the above method is a very wasteful way of doing what I want. I would basically need to serialise my data graph to a memory stream, convert it to a string, place the string inside my container, and then serialise it again.

Another issue is the length of the `string SerialisedData`. In the example I gave we only have about 5Gb of BinaryData, but what about when it starts getting larger? I know an upper-bound for a `string` on a 64-bit OS is around 2GB and significantly less for a 32-bit OS. Do streams have such a limitation? Since streams are written in blocks of bytes, it makes sense that they wouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the lazy solution: you don't have to serialize directly to a file. You can serialize to memory, and then write a file that has 1 byte for format followed by serialization data.

Second, you can get a little smarter: Open a file; write one byte to it (the format); serialize into the same string. To deserialize, read one byte to figure out the format, and then pass the stream to the deserializer; it will only read data after that one byte.

If you have the methods

```
void SerializeToStream(Stream stream, bool compress, bool encrypt);
void DeserializeFromStream(Stream stream, bool compressed, bool encrypted);
```

your code can look like this:

```
// Could also use a flags enum for these
const int EncryptBit = 1;
const int CompressBit = 2;

public void SaveToFile(string filename, bool compress, bool encrypt) {
    byte format = (byte)((compress ? CompressBit : 0) | (encrypt ? EncryptBit : 0));
    using (Stream stream = File.OpenWrite(filename)) {
        stream.WriteByte(format);
        SerializeToStream(stream, compress, encrypt);
    }
}

public void LoadFromFile(string filename) {
    using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead(filename)) {
        int format = stream.ReadByte();
        if (format < 0 || format >= 4) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unknown file format");
        }

        bool compressed = format & CompressBit != 0;
        bool encrypted = format & EncryptBit != 0;
        DeserializeFromStream(stream, compressed, encrypted);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was in that exact situation one time. I created a header for the file that I wrote out manually, followed by the compressed and/or encrypted (or possibly plain text) streams. When I opened the file, I first read in the header, then based on that information set the location of the input stream to the start of the data, and then created decompressing and/or unencrypting streams from that. It worked like a charm, was a piece of cake, and several other clichés.

My header was in plain text and included:

1. A short string that was selected randomly early in the design process to identify the file as being in the correct format.
2. A file version number, so we could change the format in the future and still read the old files.
3. Various business-specific summary information in plain text that would be displayed in a list so the user would know which file to open even if the name of the file were changed. This was not security-sensitive data, obviously.
4. An indicator that stated whether the file was encrypted, compressed, or both. Also, it could be encrypted as a whole or line-by-line to support appending encrypted data on the fly. The plain text option was used for development-purposes and the occasional data-surgery operation, but because of this design, it could be read or written to automatically just like any other file.
5. If the file were encrypted with AES, then the encryption key was stored next, which was itself encrypted with RSA, and serialized with base-64.
6. The ASCII 0x02 START OF TEXT character, which was purely for fun. (Though if it wasn't there, then reading the file would fail.)

Then came the data stream.

Comment: Thanks :) I hadn't thought of writing a header byte - but it is obvious now that I think about. They say hindsight is always 20/20.